# Stored procedure : return first five days of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to pass a single date to my stored procedure this could be any date:

`2022-04-18`

How would I be able to return the next 4 days of the week if possible to exclude weekends but its not necessary.

Expected output:

```
2022-04-18
2022-04-19
2022-04-20
2022-04-21
2022-04-22
```

Comment: Use a `TOP (5)` against your calendar table, with an appropriate `WHERE` to filter out weekends?

Comment: Or, if you just want 5 days, and don't care about weekends (as you say you both do and don't care), then just use `DATEADD` 4 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE procedure spDateMessing(@d as date)
as
with cte as
(
    select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4)) as t(n)
)
select n,cast(DATEADD(D,n,@d) as date) as Date_ from cte
```